# Angular Material not loading some imbbeded styles/classes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I installed angular material, and I wanted to use the mat-expansion-panel.
My html looks like this:

```
<mat-accordion id="players-container">
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let user of this.room.users">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      {{user.name}}
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{user.currentScore}} points
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <p *ngFor="let word of user.wordList">
    {{word}}
  </p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Now,the result of the unexpended panel looks like this:
[image]

Now I will link the example in angular's website:
https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

[image]

You can see that the right text is gray, there is a border, etc.
Why don't these default styles appear in my project, but appear in angular's site?

I am using angular material 16 as well as angular 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you correctly followed the [getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) ?

You should have very specific code in your `styles.scss`, it seems to be the problem here.

Comment: it is the problem, but it didn't appear in the getting started guide

Comment: Because it is done automatically when you use `ng add @angular/material`, which is what the getting started guide is advising